# Raster to CSV or XYZ

Tags: machine-learning, archaeology, data-mining

I'm trying to apply spatial data mining to a set of vector and raster files so I need a way to convert my raster archives into a CSV in order to run the mining

A little bit of background, my thesis is about applying data mining in archeology with the intention of modeling archaeological sites

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. We are a *problem-solving* site, so Questions always need to be asked in a way that answers the two most commonly commented questions, "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" I suspect you may have an XY Problem here, since CSV is not necessary to access raster data (it is, in fact, the *least* useful form of raster data), so you probably want to ask about the root problem, not this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `raster` and `sf` R packages to do this.

```
# Install packages (uncomment)
#install.package("raster")
#install.package("sf")

# Load packages
library(raster)
library(sf)

# Read raster data in GeoTIFF format
r <- raster::stack("C:/folder/my_raster.tif")
# Convert RasterStack object into data.frame with XY coordinates
r_df <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)
# Export data.frame to CSV
write.csv(r_df, "F:/folder/my_raster.csv")

# Read vector data in ESRI Shapefile format
# The geometry column contains the shape of your entities
s <- sf::st_read("C:/folder/my_shape.shp")
# Convert sf object into data.frame
s_df <- data.frame(s)
# Export data.frame to CSV
write.csv(s, "F:/folder/my_shape.csv")
```

You can use `head(r_df)` and `head(s_df)` to see the head of your data.